Axios this$1.originalAdapter.call is not a function after upgrading from 0.28 to 1.6
After upgrading axios versions from 0.28 to 1.6.4 our simple axios.get call throws an error of:
this$1.originalAdapter.call is not a function

The call is never made. There is no network activity.
The axios code is:
async get<T>(url: string, params?: object, configs: AxiosRequestConfig = {headers: {}} as AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<T | void> {
        
        configs = this._appendNewFlagToHeader(configs);
        configs.params = params;
        console.log("PARAMS "+ JSON.stringify(configs));
        return await axios.get(url, configs)
            .then((response) => Axios.getResponse<T>(response))
            .catch(Axios.catchErrors);
    }

The resulting configs object is:
{"headers":{"X-New":true},"params":{"username":"my-username"}}

As far as I can tell the axios call and format of the header and params object is correct.
The imports are:
import {AxiosError, AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse, default as axios} from 'axios';

To add some context the error is likely coming from a yield call outside of axios but changing the axios library leads to the error.
 // Get connection from Server
        const getAuthenticationConnectionUseCase = new GetAuthenticationConnection(httpProvider, configurations);
        const {connection} = yield call({
            context: getAuthenticationConnectionUseCase,
            fn: getAuthenticationConnectionUseCase.executeAsync
        }, {
            ...payload
        } as GetAuthenticationConnectionInput);

Not sure how axios would impact that call
We can rewrite our Axios implementation as needed but I can't even see what is wrong with the call above
